# Can you approximately detect the closure of up to 100,000 switches using a resistor chain?

Tags: circuit-design, reliability, microfabrication

Consider the following outline circuit:-

[image: wafer]

It is a series of switch controllers that can short out parts of a chain of serially connected resistors. The short is accomplished with a BJT or MOSFET. A shunt resistor at the end allows the total current through the chain to be measured and thus the number of shorted resistors estimated. This is the crux; only a    coarse estimate of the number of shorted resistors is wanted.

Assumptions:-

1. The year is 1999.
2. The circuit is custom fabricated  on a single 6" wafer of Gallium Arsenide.
3. The resistor chain would have to span the entire area of the wafer.
4. There are 100,000 switch controllers.
5. Each switch controller operates independently but is totally synchronised with a master clock.
6. The circuit operates @ 10GHz.
7. The missing detail is unimportant.
8. Cost is irrelevant.

**This is not an XY problem.** I'm re-posting a question put to me by someone, therefore it has be to critiqued as is.  I suspect that this cannot work, but why not exactly?

---

For reference, this is a proposed alternative counting solution for the [TWINKLE Device](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.19.8645&rep=rep1&type=pdf). It is a hypothetical machine for factoring prime numbers. Before you scoff, it's proposed by [Adi Shamir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_Shamir), a holy cow of cryptography and co-inventor of the RSA algorithm.

Comment: Not a VLSI expert, but my gut says the leakage currents make this a non-starter.

Comment: If you don't need to know which resistors were shorted (and only needed to know how many), you would probably make them all the same value. In that case, all you're really asking is: how accurately can you measure resistance with an amplifier like that? The answer is, pretty accurately. The real problem comes when you introduce 10GHz... I would say that you are going to have some significant difficulty dealing with that.

Comment: If you can overcome the frequency issue though, it seems like it would be pretty easy...

Comment: "Assumptions: the year is 1999" ... "This is not an XY problem". Huh, my clocks are all set wrong... Also what you really want is a 100000-input AND gate. A resistor chain *may* be able to implement that but I'm not sure what's wrong with the more traditional approach.

Comment: "only a **coarse estimate** of the number of shorted resistors is wanted." - somewhere between 0 and 100,000? No problem!

Comment: The TWINKLE would not actually work at 10 GHz, simply because light travels only about an inch in 0.1ns and the LED array needs to be quite a bit bigger than that. I also don't see why you would not just use a fully pipelined binary adder - its propagation delay is probably small compared to the one you neeed to sync all those input signals.

Comment: @immibis Have you read the paper re. AND gate? No?

Answer (score 2):

Could it work? Sure. At 10 GHz, exactly as designed? Not really. The main problem is that it takes time for changes to propagate down the wire. If you want to run at 10 GHz, that wire will have to be very short, only a couple of cm maximum. Not to mention that you would have to wait some time for things to settle down to 1 part in 100,000, or however accurately you intend to estimate the count. However, there may be a way to do something similar that could work at that speed by breaking it up into multiple stages, albeit it would certainly have more than 100 ps of latency.

Comment: Thanks for reading the paper.  Yeh, Adi talks of needing  responses not skewed by more than 10-20 ps. There's no time to settle, and I think that the resistor chain would have to cross the 6" wafer several times (as an indication of length). So it might be metres long thinking about it...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect one of 100k switch closures at 10GHz, then putting them all into a chain is absolutely the wrong way to do it. You would probably struggle to get signal propagation along a chain covering the whole of a 6" die at 1MHz, even before you start to consider precision. This is down to the physical length of the trace, as well as RC loading of the traces.

The only practical way to do it would be a hierarchical approach, aggregating progressively larger groups to a single output. A digital method would give you precision, while an analogue method would be cheaper, less precise, but probably still possible in 1999.

Comment: I suspect that the traces might be several metres long to join up 100,000 switch controllers spread uniformly over the whole wafer.

Comment: I might run this past maths.SE to get an estimate of length.

Comment: @PaulUszak A first order estimate is very easy. Assume a square array. 100k is 300^2, so the chain has 300 columns of 6", or 150ft, or 50m. Give or take a bit.

Comment: That's it then. That's why it can't work at anything like acceptable speed. It's waay too long. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably works better with R spread over an octave, not 5 decades.

So sumR=10M,
R is 33-67ohm 
exponential Step is 7e-6 (so need 20bit ADC)

Worst case is at 33 ohm= dR=228uOhm in 10M =23e-12
If V=1kV, I=100uA, dI=2.2e-15A or dV=23nV
P=I*dV = 2.3e-12W = -146dBm

Thermal noise = -171dBm

Bandwidth= 158Hz for 3dB SNR, so we can only do 100 readings/sec

---

Fets are not going to cut it as dR steps only 228u, and good fets maybe match to 0.01ohm
So probably need 100kV on the resistors, 3k3 resistors. 1Gohm total.

Now we need a 1G ohm input stage with low noise. Luckily we can capacitively couple it, and dV is only  2.3uV.

So we need a

- 20 bit ADC with 1Tohm input R and 10uV full scale.
- 100kV coupling capacitor
- 100k Opto-fets with 0.005 ohm Ron difference
- 1 each of 0603 resistor, in E600,000 resistor/decade series from 3k3 to 6k7 ohms
- 100kV wall wart

Righto - Off to Digikey then...